# The sharper duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Suppose that I have thought of a significantly sharper way to pose a question *which has already been asked on this site.* My question is a duplicate, but is likely to attract significantly better answers than the original.

Suppose that my question really is a duplicate. Suppose that it makes no sense for me to slightly modify my question in an effort to evade the antiduplication rule.

What to do?

[Here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/19710/315) is a *possible* (or at any rate plausible) example.

Comment: Hi, have you found this answer satisfactory?

Comment: Deliberately posting duplicates is narcissistic. And "My question is a duplicate, but is likely to attract significantly better answers than the original." is presumptive and arrogant.

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is that "*likely to attract significantly better answers*" is a big assumption and "*better answers*" is also arguably put for debate because it tends to become very subjective. Therefore, I would say unless there's a clear reason that distinguishes the two posts, one shouldn't try to evade the duplication rule.

Alternatively, if you feel you want to bring that older post into light again with potentially an additional question/remark attached to it, then you can always consider starting a bounty on that existing post, of the following types:

- Draw attention
- Current answers are outdated
- Improve details

whichever is more fitting to your case, and your additional remarks or questions will go in the bounty description. This way you re-open the discussions without creating a duplicate, and thanks to the bounty it will probably receive lots of feedback quickly.